# Prevent decompilation of Jar files Android

Tags: android

I have Android application which all the Java files are in a jar in the libs folder.
How can I prevent decompile that Jar? I don't want the source code to be expose?
I'm giving my project to another person, and I don't want him to see the Java files inside that Jar.
Thank's
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make code undecompilable, you can only obfuscate it:

You may use an obfuscator to make code decompilation produce very ugly code like Proguard.

```
ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier.
It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes 
bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and 
methods using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed code for 
Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.
```

Search for other products with the term obfuscator.

Comment: Thank's I want to obfuscate only the Jar file and I get the Following message:Note: there were 6 references to unknown classes.
You should check your configuration for typos. it means that the code should be free from warnings?